# Adding view to UICollectionview without moving collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll, uicollectionview

So I have a collection view with a Tableview inside it. Clicking one of the tableview cells will bring up a sort of basket on top of the collection view. You can click a maximum of 4 items. This will expand the basket. See picture.

I had the basked between the collection view and the item above the collection view. When an item is selected the height will expand and show the basket. However, this would push the collection view down and with it the selected items, so not in the same place as it was before. I tried then putting basked in the collection view with the basket top being the same as the collection view top. Still with 0 height until an item is selected. This works but obviously hides the top cells.

I tried setting setting the contentofset with the same value as the basket but that returns the previous result of pushing all the rows down.

The scenario which im looking for is to select an item. The basket shows up but doesn't move or scroll the collection view at all. But when I scroll to the top I'm still able to select the top rows.

Any idea what might solve this?

[image]
Item just selected but basked not loaded yet

[image]
Basket loaded and rows pushed down

[image] Another Item selected and all rows pushed down again.

Comment: May be using sections. And inserting a new section when a cell is clicked.

Comment: I thought of that but the collection view has different sections horizontally so the basket would scroll with the collection view while I want it to be static.